# Homework: explaining inheritance + override in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I am asked to explain the concept of inheritance + overriding based on the following code.

```
public class Item {

private String itemType;
private String serialNumber;

public Item(String serialNumber, String itemType) {
    this.setItemType(itemType);
    this.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);     
}

public String getItemType() {
    return itemType;
}

public void setItemType(String itemType) {
    this.itemType = itemType;
}

public String getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
}

public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}

public String printItem() {
    return serialNumber + "," + itemType;
}
}



public class Ipad extends Item {

private int ram;

public Ipad(String serialNumber, int ram) {
    super(serialNumber,"iPad");
    this.setRam(ram);
}

public int getRam() {
    return ram;
}

public void setRam(int ram) {
    this.ram = ram;
}

public String printItem() {
    return super.getSerialNumber() + "," + super.getItemType()+ "," + getRam() + " GB";
}   
}
```

I have a hard time actually explaining what happens, as I am very new at learning Java :) I am commenting out each line on my own, until I get more practise, but until now the step-by-step comments seems to be the best way for me to grasp things.

1) What happens in the code snip below: I assume that it is a constructor, but what do the two lines below do?

```
public Item(String serialNumber, String itemType) {
    this.setItemType(itemType);
    this.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
```

2) What happens below - are there two constructors?
As I understand, a constructor cannot be overridden.
I assume that the super is invoking the constructor from the superclass, but then a new ram variable is added. So is this what is called constructor chaining, if it's not being overridden?

```
public Ipad(String serialNumber, int ram) {
    super(serialNumber,"iPad");
    this.setRam(ram);
}
```

3) What is being overridden?

4) How (besides the use of the extends keyword + the super keywords) do I explain inheritance with this example?

Comment: Please try to limit 1 question per...question.

Comment: Sorry, I realize it looks overwhelming.. :)

Comment: I would suggest that you try your source code using the many answers that you'd find here or googling and some typing by yourself. Try inheritance's concepts and limitations as you type: for instance try using a private method of a base class from a derived class. It will not compile.

So try all of them and you will get a good picture. Even change the base class if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The snippet you provided is creating an item object with the parameters for the serial number and item type; which as you can see in the Item class' constructor, simply sets the serial number and item type to the provided arguments.
Constructors typically have arguments which are required for the objects to be functional, and that is why they are there. To ensure the object is fully 'constructed'.

```
public Item(String serialNumber, String itemType) {
this.setItemType(itemType);
this.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
```

2) Constructor chaining is when an object references another one of its constructors, allowing for construction functionality to be reused with different arguments having been provided to the object for construction.
In the example you gave, the IPad object simply inherits the Item constructor. As a subclass, IPad is required to reference the Item's constructor within it's own construction. This must be done on the first line.
In that way, it is true that you cannot override constructors, however, you do add additional functionality to the construction of the IPad class not present in the Item class, by setting the ram to that which was provided in the IPad constructor arguments.

```
public Ipad(String serialNumber, int ram) {
super(serialNumber,"iPad");
this.setRam(ram);
```

3) You are overriding nothing in this example other than #printItem, which adds the item's ram to the printed string representation of the item. Other than that you are simply inheriting and adding onto the Item class through the Ipad class.

4) You can explain this using plain english. The IPad is an item, and has all the functionality and data as an item, with the addition of it's own IPad specific functionality and data.

You could also compare this to another situation. Such as with rectangles and squares. A square is a rectangle, however, a rectangle is not necessarily a square, though it could be. An IPad is an item, however, an Item is not necessarily an IPad, though it could be.
It's is a specification, a branch of its more general parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Justisr! That cleared it up for me so much :) So there is actually no overriding present here?

Answer (score 0):

You can explain it using this example:

```
Item item = new Ipad("serial", 123);
System.out.println(item.printItem());
```

You can say that the method `printItem()` is executed with the `Ipad` class implementation because `Ipad` inherits it from `Item` and overrides it.

So, `printItem()` will print `"serial, iPad, 123"`